# Themeforest theme integration with Yii framework

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, theming

I have gone through Yii documentation and successfully implemented two different themes for back end and front end of the website. Yii doesnt have good themes and I found themeforest having awesome bootstrap themes. So I installed Yii-booster and downloaded a themeforest theme with bootstrap support.
I was wondering how to integrate it?

1)Do I have to make a new folder in themes folder, and replace css,js, images folder in root 
directory

OR

2)Replace the js,css and other folder/files at path protected/extensions/bootstrap/assets

OR

3) Any other way ??

Answer (score 1):

Apply a simple logic. Just copy the theme and make particular layout ,then call the layout in the controllers according to your need.